# ¿Alguien podría explicarme por que mi contador solo suma hasta 1?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, javascript-objeto

He estado haciendo una mini aplicacion de piedra, papel o tijera que se divide en dos que se encuentran en dos archivos `html` **main.html** y **options.html**. Las partes este proyecto son:

> El "login" y el "juego" en sí

Y yo tengo 2 archivos `js` los cuales son **main.js** y **box.js** conectados a dos documentos `html` distintos también. En el **main.js** tengo los objetos de jugador 1, jugador 2 y computadora dependiendo de si el jugador uno quiere jugar contra otro jugador o contra la computadora.

Ahora lo que estoy haciendo sería la parte en la que un jugador juega con otro jugador con los objetos **playerOne** y **playerTwo**, que serían los objetos de los jugadores, y entre las propiedades de cada objeto está la propiedad **points** en cada objeto por separado que es donde se pondría los puntos que ganan cada uno.

El primer problema es que al jugar una vez, sea el jugador que gane al principio, suma 1 punto, pero cuando juego de vuelta le suma 2 puntos. Por ejemplo si jugador 1 ganó dos veces, queda con 3 puntos en vez de solo 2.

Luego aplique una solución que me dijeron por aqui en stack y no funciono. Así que intente lo que hice ahora en mi codigo que les voy a mostrar y solo suma hasta 1. Por favor necesito que alguien me explique que sucede y que me explique una forma de que funcione. Mi problema se encuentra en el archivo `JS` en la parte de `userOneWins()` y `userTwoWins`

```js
function compareResults(user,enemy){

    switch(user + " " + enemy){
        case "rock scissors":
        case "scissors paper":
        case "paper rock":
            userOneWins(user,enemy,playerOne.points);
            break;
        case "scissors rock":
        case "paper scissors":
        case "rock paper":
            if(enemy===playerTwo.option){
                userTwoWins(user,enemy, playerTwo.points);
            }else{
                computerWins(user,enemy);
            }
            
            break;
        default:
            winnerText.innerHTML="It´s a draw!"
            break
    }
    
}



//MI PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI
function userOneWins(a,b,c){
    c=0;
    if(a==="rock" && b==="scissors"){
         winnerText.innerHTML= `Rock beats scissors. You won ${playerOne.name}`;
         c++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="scissors" && b==="paper"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `scissors cuts paper. You won ${playerOne.name}`;
         c++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="paper" && b==="rock"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `Paper covers rock. You won ${playerOne.name}`;
        c++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    userScore.innerHTML= c;
    stadistics(playerOne.name,playerTwo.name,playerOne.points,playerTwo.points);
}

//MI PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI TAMBIEN
function userTwoWins(a,b,c){
    c=0;
    if(a==="scissors" && b==="rock"){
         winnerText.innerHTML= `Rock beats scissors. You won ${playerTwo.name}`;
        c++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="paper" && b==="scissors"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `scissors cuts paper. You won ${playerTwo.name}`;
         c++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="rock" && b==="paper"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `Paper covers rock. You won ${playerTwo.name}`;
         c++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    enemyScore.innerHTML=c;
    stadistics(playerOne.name,playerTwo.name,playerOne.points,playerTwo.points);
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Sin mirar tu código (a ver quién es el *guapo* que se lo lee **todo**), estoy seguro de que tu problema podría reproducirse en unas cuantas líneas menos :-)

Comment: Pincha en el enlace y lo verás :-)

Comment: si mira ya lo habia leido antes solo no sabia que se decía si pero mi problema se encuentra en el archivo box.js en la parte de userWins(). Yo he puesto los demas archivos para que se entienda el contexto del proyecto. Gracias igual por la ayuda

Comment: Explicaste muy bien el problema, pero donde fallaste fue soltando todo el código para que nos metamos a analizar todo eso y a tratar de adivinar dónde está el problema. Al menos puedes decir: *tengo el problema en esta parte, donde espero que ocurra esto pero ocurre tal cosa*.

Comment: Ahhh claro gracias ahora lo edito muchas gracias.

Comment: probablemente lo que te esta sucediendo es que en lugar de un contador estas usando un acumulador, pero como no puedo ver el atributo points de las clases que lo tienen, no podría decirte con certeza. También puedes probar agregando un -1 después de realizar la suma y antes de imprimir el puntaje.

Comment: Los métodos `userWins()`y user `TwoWins()` que mencionas no aparecen en el código. Además no tiene sentido tener un método por cada jugador que gane: `userWins, user2Wins, user3Wins, .... user999999Wins`.... sería una locura, ¿no sería más fácil tener un sólo método y pasarle en parámetro el jugador que ganó y hacer lo que haya que hacer usando esa información?

Comment: si la verdad no lo habia pensado en serio gracias lo hare asi pero por ahora necesito que funcione y para eso primero quiero resolver el problema en cuestión. Las funciones se llaman userOneWins() y userTwoWins debido a que solo puede haber dos jugadores y la computadora.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes trate de seguir sus consejos sobre mi codigo para que se entienda mi problema y lo edite. Espero que se entienda y si alguien es tan amable de solo mirarlo y explicarme el problema se lo voy a agradecer

Comment: por favor gentee necesito su ayuda estoy desesperado.

Comment: Estás inicializando la variable c en ambas funciones a 0 cada vez que entras, por lo que cuando sumas un punto al jugador que gana siempre queda en 1. Creo que está ahí el error.

Comment: no creo acabo de intentar sacando esa linea que dice "c=0;" y sigue funcionando igual. Pero gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente tu error esta en esas dos funciones que señalas, lo que haces es que sumas puntos cada vez que las invocas y eso no deberías hacerlo sino hacerlo con una función diferente o con un argumento o con sentencias.

Tus funciones tendrían que quedar así para que no sumen puntos, únicamente cuando gana un jugador

```
function userOneWins(a,b){
    if(a==="rock" && b==="scissors"){
         winnerText.innerHTML= `Rock beats scissors. You won ${playerOne.name}`;
         playerOne.points++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="scissors" && b==="paper"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `scissors cuts paper. You won ${playerOne.name}`;
         playerOne.points++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="paper" && b==="rock"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `Paper covers rock. You won ${playerOne.name}`;
         playerOne.points++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    points.innerHTML= `${playerOne.points}:${playerTwo.points}`;
}

function userTwoWins(a,b){
    if(a==="scissors" && b==="rock"){
         winnerText.innerHTML= `Rock beats scissors. You won ${playerTwo.name}`;
         playerTwo.points++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="paper" && b==="scissors"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `scissors cuts paper. You won ${playerTwo.name}`;
         playerTwo.points++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    if(a==="rock" && b==="paper"){
        winnerText.innerHTML= `Paper covers rock. You won ${playerTwo.name}`;
         playerTwo.points++; // suma +1 por victoria
    }
    points.innerHTML= `${playerOne.points}:${playerTwo.points}`;
}
```

Comment: gracias por la solucion pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: si disculpa no me di cuenta gracias