# ¿Alguien podria explicarme que sucede con las propiedades de mis objetos problemas en mi proyecto?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, javascript-objeto

He estado haciendo una mini aplicación de piedra, papel o tijera que se divide en dos y se encuentran en dos archivos `html` **main.html** y **options.html**. Las partes este proyecto son:

> El "login" y el "juego" en sí

Y yo tengo 2 archivos `js` los cuales son **main.js** y **box.js** conectados a dos documentos `html` distintos también. En el **main.js** tengo los objetos de jugador 1, jugador 2 y computadora dependiendo de si el jugador uno quiere jugar contra otro jugador o contra la computadora.

Mi problema es que, como ya he dicho, mi jugador 1 puede jugar con otro jugador o contra la computadora. Entonces la computadora también es un objeto llamado computer que tiene la propiedad **play**, como el objeto de jugador 2 que también la tiene y sirve para saber, al apretar el botón, si juegas contra computadora o  contra otro jugador.

El problema aquí es que la propiedad **play** de ambos objetos me da que es verdadera y solo me deja jugar contra otro jugador, cuando en realidad lo que tendría que suceder es que si yo aprieto el boton vs computer, debería jugar contra la computadora y si aprieto el de vs player, debería dejarme jugar contra un jugador.

De ante mano muchas gracias por leer esto y disculpen de antemano si no me he explicado lo suficiente.

Mi problema o problemas están señalados en el código con comentarios pero básicamente se encuentran en las funciones `loginPlayerTwo` y `loginComputer`

```
"use strict";
//main.js "la parte login"
let playerOne= {
    name: "",
    turn: true,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let playerTwo= {
    name:"" ,
    play: false, 
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let computer= {
    name: "Computer",
    play: false,
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

//selecting DOM elements

//login page
const firstInput= document.getElementById("input");
const firstPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton");
const compButton= document.getElementById("computer");
const playerButton= document.getElementById("player");
const secondInput= document.getElementById("input-two");
const secondPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton-two");

function calling(){
    loginPlayerOne();
    loginPlayerTwo(); 
    loginComputer();
}


function loginPlayerOne(){
    firstPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        let data= playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
        JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(playerOne.name);
        console.log(playerOne);
        if(typeof playerOne.name==="string"){
            localStorage.setItem("playerOne",JSON.stringify(playerOne));
        };
    });


    document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
        if(event.keyCode===13){
            playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
            console.log(playerOne.name);
            if(typeof playerOne.name==="string"){
                localStorage.setItem("playerOne",JSON.stringify(playerOne));
            };
        }
    });


}

//MI PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI
function loginPlayerTwo(){
    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{ 
        playerTwo.play=true;
        computer.play=false;

        if(computer.play===false){
            playerTwo.play= true;
        }

        secondPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;

            console.log(playerTwo.name); 
            console.log("Estas jugando contra un jugador");
            console.log(playerTwo.play);
            console.log(computer.play);

            if(typeof playerTwo.name==="string"){
                choosingEnemy();
                localStorage.setItem("playerTwo",JSON.stringify(playerTwo));
            };

        })


        document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
            if(event.keyCode===13){
                playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;

                console.log(playerTwo.name);
                console.log("Estas jugando contra un jugador");
                console.log(playerTwo.play);
                console.log(computer.play);

                if(typeof playerTwo.name==="string"){
                    choosingEnemy();
                    localStorage.setItem("playerTwo",JSON.stringify(playerTwo));
                }

            }
        })



    })
}

//MI PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI
function loginComputer(){
    compButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        playerTwo.play= false;
        computer.play= true;

        if(playerTwo.play===false){
            computer.play=true;   
        }

        console.log("Estas jugando contra la computadora");
        console.log(playerTwo.play);
        console.log(computer.play);

        if(playerTwo.play===false && computer.play===true){
            choosingEnemy();
            localStorage.setItem("computer",JSON.stringify(computer));   
        }


    })
};

//HE INTENTADO HACER ESTO ANTES DE PONER MIS OBJETOS EN EL LOCAL STORGE PERO NO SIRVE
function choosingEnemy(){
    if(playerTwo.play===false){
        computer.play=true;
        playerTwo.play= false;   
    } else{
        playerTwo.play= true;
        computer.play= false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta luce como un duplicado de esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321357/alguien-podria-explicarme-que-sucede-con-los-n%c3%bameros-en-mi-contador  y de esta también https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321317/alguien-podria-explicarme-que-sucede-con-los-n%c3%bameros-y-las-propiedades-de-mis-o es así?

Comment: sii la segunda parte de esa duda es la misma lo que sucede es que preferia preguntar por separado para que se entiendan mejor los problemas y eliminar esa gran pregunta tediosa

Comment: te recomiendo dejar solo una pregunta y tratar de ser mas claro, solo colocando el código mínimo necesario para poder ayudarte, ya que de lo contrario pudieran cerrarte todas las preguntas marcandolas como duplicadas

Comment: sii disculpa es que todavia soy medio nuevo aqui en stackoverflow apenas lo descubri hace unas semans mil disculpas y diganme si este problema no se entiende y lo edito muchas gracias

Comment: Yo te recomiendo elimines todos los duplicados y solo dejes una donde expongas tus dudas de forma clara, coloques solo el código mínimo necesario y aclares que problemas has tenido

Comment: ya he eliminado el duplicado gracias por el consejo y ya he señalado en el problema y en el codigo donde a mi parecer se encuentra el problema. Gracias de ante mano por los consejos y soluciones al problema en si

Comment: Hola buenas tardes trate de seguir sus consejos sobre mi codigo para que se entienda mi problema y lo edite. Espero que se entienda y si alguien es tan amable de solo mirarlo y explicarme el problema se lo voy a agradecer

Comment: Por favor gentee necesito su ayuda estoy desesperado.